# MySQL Reverse search

Tags: mysql, search, query-optimization, reverse

I have the following query that I've added the ORDER BY DESC LIMIT to reverse the order and limit the results to 30.  It's working fine but, I'm wondering if there is any other faster way to do the job.

```
$q = "SELECT r.*,
us.username,
a.title, a.id
FROM #__rate r  
LEFT JOIN #__users us ON r.voter_id=us.id
LEFT JOIN #__tek_reviews a ON r.reviews_id=a.id
WHERE r.user_rated_id=" . $db->quote($userid) . 'ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 30';
```

I suppose that this way first completes the search and then order and limit the results. Is there any way to start searching in reverse and limit the results?

I show somewhere someone using the REVERSE () function to accomplice the same but, I can't make it work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [REVERSE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) is extremely unlikely to help; it is a string function for turning things like "this" into "siht". About the only thing obvious that could help this query is making sure the fields used in join conditions and your order by clause are indexed.

Comment: `JOINS` are fast. Try to see if some tables are not needed at all in the Query. Other than that don't print what is not needed. This query should work easily for around 1 million entries of matched items within few seconds.

Comment: Thanks Guys! I've read the manual about the REVERSE function and it is exactly as you say, but I've read a blog post which included a couple examples also that use it to reverse the order and I thought that I'm missing something. Anyway, thanks again. By the way the Query above, it's not my query actually.. : - )

Comment: I'd be curious of the blog post; I can't immediately think of any situation where REVERSE could be used for such a purpose. ("231" and "342" wouldn't even change order.)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL REVERSE(str) - Returns the string str with the order of the characters reversed. This function is not affect on select result order, so it can not help you.
I think your query fast enough, because it use primary key to get result.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(user_rated_id, id)
```

on `#__rate` should make it efficient.  My [*index cookbook*] covers the case of building this index and having it be useful all the way into `LIMIT`.

`DESC` does not impact the problem.  The scan can start at the end of the single specified `user_rated_id` rows and scan backward for 30 rows.

To determine whether it is touching only 30 rows (versus the entire table):

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```